# sas proc surveyselect with contstraint on column

Tags: sas

i'm trying to create a unique sample dataset with `proc surveyselect` based on 2 columns.
I have a simple table with `person_id` and `household_id`. in this case person_id is my "primary key" which is the main input for creating a sample. BUT i need to make sure that I don't mix household_id between sample and base data.
So if household_id = 123 is the sample, it is not allowed to appear in the base data (even with another person_id) and vice versa.

do you have a handy idea? all my solution pre- or postprocessing will influence the sample sizes.

Thanks!!
E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found, `proc surveyselect` does not allow for this sort of constraint. You're going to have to accept a slight distortion in your sampling if you want to accommodate it. My suggestion would be to proceed as follows:

- Use proc surveyselect to create a random sample
- Identify all household_ids in the sample dataset that are also present in the base dataset. Let's say there are N of these.
- Create another sample of size N from the base dataset with all of the household_ids in the original sample excluded.
- Put all of the matching household_id rows back in the base dataset, remove them from the original sample, and append the new sample to the original sample.

Comment: Hi, thats whtat i am doing right now. i hoped to find an out of the box solution :) thank user667489